# webview not loading website from external link

Tags: android, android-webview

I am having issues with getting a URL to load in my webview that was clicked on in a email. It prompts to use my app which works fine and dandy, however its just loading a blank page. Here is my code.

```
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;



    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "appdebug";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        Log.i(TAG, "webview working");



    }
    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.i(TAG, "overrideurl");
            if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.example.com")) {
                // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
                return false;
            }
            // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;

        }


    }
}
```

In Logcat its reporting the webview is working however i am not seeing anything from the overrideURl. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you load the same URL with the default browser of your device?

Comment: Yes i can that works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer.

```
 Uri uri = this.getIntent().getData();


    try {

        URL urls = new URL(uri.getScheme(), uri.getHost(), uri.getPort(), uri.getPath()+ "?"+ uri.getQuery());



        Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(urls));

       webView.loadUrl(String.valueOf(urls));

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`is, I believe used for opening links withing the `webview` and is not looked at when the app is loaded from an url outside the app.

Answer (score 0):

It will work

public class DynamicWebView extends ActionBarActivity {
    WebView web;

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    String url = bundle.getString("WebIntent");
    Log.e("On Click Url", url);

    final RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(), getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight());

    layout.setLayoutParams(params);

    setContentView(layout);

    web = new WebView(this);
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    web.loadUrl(url);

    layout.addView(web);
    layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```

}

Comment: I copied your code over. The variable "web" is in red. Should "web = new WebView(this);" be "WebView web = new WebView(this);"

Comment: WebView web = new WebView(this); I declared the variable globally

Comment: UPDATE: I saw the code outside the snippet. I am createing a new java file now. Thanks!

Comment: So i created a new java file and put that code in it and made the changes. Its not working. Still a blank

Comment: Have you seen warn in logcat while running? What is your external link? Is that html page or what?

Comment: Final try. Add this web.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient()); before web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  And add this in same java file          private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{
  
  @Override
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
   view.loadUrl(url);
   return true;
  }
 }

Comment: Hey @megphn.. your question is closed ah? I mean your problem is solved or not? If yes, mark my answer as accepted, else reply with your queries. Otherwise, this question will be in pending status.

Answer (score 0):

Add this permission in manifest.xml after closing tag

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```